# Redirect access to .htaccess to another file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I was playing around with .htaccess files and I was wondering, completely out of curiosity, is it possible to redirect access to the .htaccess file itself to another file?

Example:

User goes to `http://www.example.com/.htaccess`

I want the user to be redirected to `index.php?foo=bar`

I've tried the following:

```
Redirect 301 /.htaccess /index.php?foo=bar
```

And

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?foo=bar [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

These methods work on any other file, but the `.htaccess` file itself always results in a `403 Forbidden` page showing up.

Is this possible? If not, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your webservers configuration file you will find some directive that prevents users from accessing `.htaccess` or `.htpasswd` file from the browser. For instance if I open up my apache configuration, located at `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` I can spot the following lines:

```
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
# 
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

So you should be able to change the above to:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

you also need to make sure that you have the correct file permission on the `.htaccess` file and finally restart your server using:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Of course doing the above would not be very secure.

Comment: Of course! It seems so obvious now that I'm looking at it.